# Why does upsampling in the frequency domain produces replicas of the signal in spatial/time domain

Tags: fourier-transform, upsampling

The experiment is the following:

Given a 1d signal, e.g., a vector of values $f$. Let $F$ be its DFT, i.e., $F=fftshift(fft(f))$, shift is just to have DC centered. Then we upsample $F$ as $uF=upsample(F,2)$. Note that we do NOT interpolate, juste upsample. Like @Fat32 mentioned,  signal expander, just stuff with 0s.

Now if we look at the $ifft(uF)$ or $abs(ifft(uF))$ , - let us disregard problems of even/odd nb of values? -, what we see is that the temporal or spatial signal $f$ is duplicated. Of course, the size of the signal is doubled but that doesn't intuitively imply that the signal will appear 2 times in the other domain. Although,  for a pure sine wave, for the example at 1 Hz i.e. 1 cycle only over the vector, stuffing zeros in between in the DFT will have the effect of just "moving" the peaks further apart therefore resulting in higher frequency. For such a simple sinusoid, 2 waves appear in the temporal domain instead of 1, for the non-upsampled one.

I m looking for an intuition explanation of why that is and also a mathematical one (such as Like the fact that sampling is modeled by a multiplication by a dirac comb and signal trucation multiplication by a square function. )

Comment: I believe this already has answers... please search the site for expander-compressor-DFT

Comment: Ok well in fact I believe you have answered the same question here indeed: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53598/idft-of-upsampling-in-frequency-domain

Comment: so in summary it is related to the periodicity of the DFT and the signal itself, which itself stems from the fact that they are discretized in both domains, frequency and time.

Comment: yes it was a very similar question. In fact if you think from a **duality** perspective, they are essentially the same questions. As the behaviour in time and frequency domains are almost the same. And as for your intuiton, yes it's linked with both domains being a *sampled* domain, making the reciprocal a periodic domain, and they're duals, due to (almost) symmetric forward and inverse transforms.

Comment: I think yes thanks